# Issues Starting my Simple Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am starting to learn Spring Boot following a Pluralsight training.

I am doing a very simple Rest Service using Spring boot and i only have a couple lines of code. So i guess the issue will be in the pom.xml configs.

please see below everything i have:

**pom.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>das-boot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <name>das-boot</name>
    <url>http://mave.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**App.java**

```js
package com.boot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        //System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

**HomeController.java**

```js
package com.boot.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "Das Boot, reporting for duty";
    }
}
```

**Error Logs**
[image: Error Logs Screen shot]

**Complete Error Logs**

```html
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=49835 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:/Users/johnmartinez/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/181.5087.20/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=49836:/Users/johnmartinez/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/181.5087.20/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Users/johnmartinez/Documents/OneDrive/Programming Workspace/Pluralsight Workspace/Spring Boot/das-boot/target/classes:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.13/slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.13/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.13/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.13.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.13/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.30.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.30.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.30/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.2.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.4/jackson-databind-2.6.4.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.4/jackson-annotations-2.6.4.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.4/jackson-core-2.6.4.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar" com.boot.App

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.1.RELEASE)

2018-06-09 19:26:11.742  INFO 7952 --- [           main] com.boot.App                             : Starting App on Johns-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 7952 (started by johnmartinez in /Users/johnmartinez/Documents/OneDrive/Programming Workspace/Pluralsight Workspace/Spring Boot/das-boot)
2018-06-09 19:26:11.746  INFO 7952 --- [           main] com.boot.App                             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-06-09 19:26:11.788  INFO 7952 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1b8a29df: startup date [Sat Jun 09 19:26:11 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/Users/johnmartinez/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-06-09 19:26:12.246  WARN 7952 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.jacksonProperties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jackson.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate Configuration.
2018-06-09 19:26:12.246  INFO 7952 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-06-09 19:26:12.252 ERROR 7952 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.jacksonProperties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jackson.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate Configuration.
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
 at com.boot.App.main(App.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.jacksonProperties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jackson.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate Configuration.
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jackson.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate Configuration.
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to instantiate Configuration.
 at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:279) ~[validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:223) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor$LocalValidatorFactory.run(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:424) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.getValidator(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:361) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.determineValidator(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:344) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:275) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.getJavaRelease(Version.java:36) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
 at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
 at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
 at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:31) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
 at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276) ~[validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:na]
 ... 36 common frames omitted

2018-06-09 19:26:12.254  INFO 7952 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: unknown

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Adding last part of the log: -> 
`2018-06-09 19:26:12.254  INFO 7952 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: unknown`

Comment: Do not post screenshots of stack traces, copy/paste the COMPLETE stack trace into the question and format as `code`.

Comment: @JimGarrison thanks for the feedback... I have added the complete log.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, it seems that you are using an old version of spring (1.3.1.RELEASE) with JDK 10 (as in the first line of the screenshot).

If I were you, I would upgrade spring version to a newer [one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent) (such as 2.0.2.RELEASE) or downgrade to JDK 8.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks!!!! I changer the Spring dependency version to 2.0.2 Release.... Thanks again @ThiagoProcaci